# How to check if a section title (or any heading) is the first line of a new page?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking, conditionals

I would like to be able to use an `\if` command to check if a `\section` appears on the **first line of a new page**. If a section heading is the first line of a new page, I would like to then adjust some of the spacing between the section heading and the header by modifying `\headsep`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

**More info (edit):** The issue arises whenever you don't forcibly add new pages to separate sections. If you were to write continuously, then, whenever TeX decides to insert a page break, the spacing arguments native to `\section` are suppressed ***iff*** the page break occurs right before a new section.

Hence, if, for instance, you have long, ruled headers, the lack of spacing looks odd:
[image: Page breaks suppress spacing]

As far as I know, TeX doesn't have a built-in counter for line numbering that can be used to check if a heading appears on the first line of a new page. You don't know when a page break is likely to occur, either. Thus, although I have a specific purpose for finding a way to check if something is on the first (or *nth* line) of a page, it might still help others with different purposes.

Comment: It seems I solved this myself... My solution requires the `lineno`, `fancyhdr`, and `color` packages, so it is not an elegant solution by any means. First initiate `lineno` to insert line numbers to your document; `lineno` adds a counter called `linenumber` which you can reset for every new page by adding \@addtoreset{linenumber}{page}.

Comment: ... Then....

Define a new `fancypagestyle{y}` that adds the x shift `\setlength{\headsep}{x}` 

Then, when you define your `\def\@makesectionhead#1` macro, add: `\ifnum\value{linenumber}=1\thispagestyle{y}\else\fi`. 

Lastly, \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}} to hide line#s. :)

Comment: But changing `\headsep` will shift the whole text block down.

Comment: @egreg. That's true. You could counteract it by reducing `\textheight` by an equal amount within the new pagestyle. Keeping it in a `fancypagestyle` and using `\thispagestyle` should ensure that both changes are only applied to the single page where the condition of the first line being a section heading is met.

Answer (score 3):

This solution requires the `lineno`, `fancyhdr`, and `color` packages, so it is not elegant.

First, Initiate `lineno` to insert line numbers to your document (use `\linenumbers` after `begin{document}`); `lineno` adds a counter called `linenumber` which you can force-reset for each new page by adding `\@addtoreset{linenumber}{page}` to your `.cls` (class/style) file.

Define a new `fancypagestyle{y}` that adds the required additional space (x) between header and the first line using `\setlength{\headsep}{x}`.

Then, when you define your `\def\@makesectionhead#1{}` macro that creates or prints the section number and name, add `\ifnum\value{linenumber}=1\thispagestyle{y}\else\fi` as the last line before closing with `}`.

Lastly, use `\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}}` to hide line numbers by changing them to white.

Comment: As egreg noted: changing `\headsep` will shift the whole textblock. To counteract this, simple add a second `\setlength` command in the newly defined pagestyle that reverses the change in `\textheight`. So, if you increase `\headsep` by 1em, reduce `\textheight` by 1em.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather horrible hack:

```
\makeatletter
\let\john@@section\section
\def\section{\goodbreak\@nobreaktrue
  \vspace*{3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}\john@@section}
\makeatother
```

The argument of `\vspace` has been copied from the class definition of `\section`.

(It's quite hard to understand the need for this.)