# Frame for a box depending on the position in the page

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, framed

I would like to write a command `\begin{myFramedBox} ... \end{myFramedBox}` such that:

- If the block inside `\begin{myFramedBox} ... \end{myFramedBox}` is at the beginning of the page, then it is printed normally.
- Else: it is printed with a rule above it.

These commands would allow me to have blocks that are separated by rules unless there is a pagebreak.

How to do that? (I'm open to solution with `tcolorbox`)

Comment: \pagetotal should be 0pt at the top of a page, but it is only changed between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty hack using the code from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41302/101651.

Let me know if it works in your case.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- For testing purpose only
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
%Code from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41302/101651
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{linenumber}{page}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myFramedBox}
    {\ifnumequal{\thelinenumber}{0}{}{\vspace{10pt}\hrule\vspace{10pt}}}{\par}
\begin{document}\linenumbers
\blindtext
\begin{myFramedBox} 
This has a rule above 
\end{myFramedBox}
\blindtext\newpage
\begin{myFramedBox} 
This has no rule above 
\end{myFramedBox}
\blindtext
\begin{myFramedBox} 
This has a rule above 
\end{myFramedBox}
\newpage
\begin{myFramedBox} 
This has no rule above 
\end{myFramedBox}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try in the coming days and let you know.

Comment: @Colas You're welcome! I hope it works.

Comment: Hi CarLaTeX. Unfortunately, it does not work. Thanks again anyway!

Comment: @Colas What error/anomaly does it gives you?

Comment: It's difficult to know because I've copied/pasted your solution in my document. Basically, the majority of the text disappears!

Comment: @Colas Are you able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem? Could you add it to your question?